# after to make join between 2 tables a field is not recognize

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins

I made join between two attribute tables with a common field and then I tried to use python to read a field and now field is not recognized on the new table.. Is it normal? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Generaly non recognized fields is not normal... But a lot more info is needed. What have you done(cursors often create locks on tables when not handled probperly for example), what are your field data types and so on...

Comment: Have you verified the field name didn't change after the join?  If you made a temporary join, your problem may be fully qualified field names depending on how you are trying to read the data (e.g. cursors).

Comment: when I go to field properties, in this table that fields aren't recognized, all of them have the name "nametable.namefield" inspite of only have "namefield". But the original fields of this table are recognized and the new fields (after join) aren't recognized

Comment: To access fields I use: 
p_sub='F:\Trab\P_ArcGis\ArcGIS\Model\Lin_p_trocos.shp'
p_field='P_prod'
po_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(p_sub,p_field)
p_sub=[]
for row in po_cursor:
    p_sub.append(row)
p_prod_sub=[i[0] for i in p_sub]

Answer (score 2):

The field name changes with a join. The feature class or shapefile name is added to the start of the field, and a period is placed between the feature class/shapefile name and field name. `os` is a good module to use to create your new field name. Here's an example of how to create the joined field name:

```
>>> import os
>>> fld = "P_prod"
>>> shpFile = r"F:\Trab\P_ArcGis\ArcGIS\Model\Lin_p_trocos.shp"
>>> shpFileName = os.path.basename (shpFile)
>>> shpFileName
'Lin_p_trocos.shp'
>>> shpName = os.path.splitext (shpFileName) [0]
>>> shpName
'Lin_p_trocos'
>>> fldName = "{0}.{1}".format (shpName, fld)
>>> fldName
'Lin_p_trocos.P_prod'
```

[image]

Comment: can I use this code on my python script to "copy" a field of an attribute table to other?
I tryed to add a new field and I saved this and when I run python script, it gives me an error  "A column was specified that does not exist."